# send events from a windows service

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, windows-10, keyboard-events

I am developing a project in **C#** to control a device. For that, I am using a Windows Service ([Windows Service Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141(v=vs.85).aspx)) that reads the input from the service and then sends the resulting output using **SendInput()** ([SendInput function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)).

The service itself is already working, but it isn't able to generate any kind of event.

This is the code of the OnStart() function of the service:

```
   ///<summary>
    /// Executed at reception of Start command.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="args">
    /// It must contain the source and name used for the debug log, or be empty. 
    /// The source and log must be already registered, otherwise a write attempt would fail and leave the service in an undefined state.
    ///</param>
    protected override void OnStart( string[] args ) {
        // Update the service state to Start Pending
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus() {
            dwServiceType = ServiceConstants.serviceType,
            dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING,
            dwWaitHint = ServiceConstants.startAndStopLatency,
            dwControlsAccepted = ServiceControls.SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP
        };
        SetServiceStatus( this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus );

        // We use the default source and log names
        string logSourceName = LogConstants.logSourceName;
        string logName = LogConstants.logName;

        // If the arguments define an existent source and log, we actualize our variables
        if( args.Count() > 0 && System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists( args[0] ) ) logSourceName = args[0];
        if( args.Count() > 1 && System.Diagnostics.EventLog.Exists( args[1] ) ) logName = args[1];

        debugLog.Source = logSourceName;
        debugLog.Log = logName;

        debugLog.WriteEntry( "In OnStart." );

        //This is the part of the code that should generate an "H" key
        //pressing.
        //It works out of the service.
        //InputFactory.getKeyDown() and InputFactory.getKeyUp() generate the
        //corresponding INPUT struct to press and release a key.
        try {
            EventLib.INPUT i1 = InputFactory.getKeyDownINPUT( EventLib.ScanCodeShort.KEY_H );
            EventLib.INPUT i2 = InputFactory.getKeyUpINPUT( EventLib.ScanCodeShort.KEY_H );
            EventLib.INPUT[] ii1 = new EventLib.INPUT[] { i1 };
            EventLib.INPUT[] ii2 = new EventLib.INPUT[] { i2 };
            EventLib.SendInput( 1, ii1, EventLib.INPUT.Size );
            EventLib.SendInput( 1, ii2, EventLib.INPUT.Size );
        } catch( InvalidOperationException ioe ) {
            debugLog.WriteEntry( "Error: " + ioe.Message );
        } catch( System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception w32e ) {
            debugLog.WriteEntry( "Error: " + w32e.Message );
        } catch( System.IO.FileNotFoundException fnfe ) {
            debugLog.WriteEntry( "Error: " + fnfe.Message );
        }

        // Update the service state to Running
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
        serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = ServiceControls.SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | ServiceControls.SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE;
        SetServiceStatus( this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus );
    }
```

The service runs in the LocalSystem account.

Comment: A service is not designed to interact with a user, so maybe this causes an issue?  Maybe this can help a bit:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502(v=vs.85).aspx